# Perl WWW::Mechanize and cookies

Tags: perl, cookies, mechanize

Got some problems with WWW::Mechanize.

The page I'm trying to load contains Javascript, which waits for 30 seconds, and then parse a button I need to click (to confirm that I've agreed with site terms:) )

I've understood than Mechanize doesn't work with JS, so I need to get this page with cookies, that this site puts into my browser when I press this button.

These cookies are smth like this: agreed=>1, lastvisit=>1388753990, lastseen=>0

How can I get the needed page with these cookies "on board"?

Code:

```
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new;
my $agent      = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => $cookie_jar );

$cookie_jar->set_cookie("agreed"=>1,"lastseen"=>0,"lastvisit"=>1388753990);

$agent->get( 'http://www.example.com' );

print $agent->content();
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can use `LWPx::ParanoidAgent` for simple queries and set the cookie_jar, you can find a workaround by setting the cookie manually, but if you need to execute JS you can use `JavaScript::SpiderMonkey`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want real Mechanize move to [WWW-Mechanize-Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox/)
Then you get real working JS environment:

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->get('http://ursite.com');

# The submit button is generated after the page has loaded

my $retries = 10;
while ($retries-- and ! $mech->is_visible( xpath => '//*[@id="submit"]' )) {
      sleep 1;
};
die "Timeout" if 0 > $retries;

# Now the element exists
$mech->click({xpath => '//*[@id="submit"]'});
```

Comment: Perfect! Спасибо:) But I've got a small problem with installation WWW::Mechanize::Firefox on server without video card:) Is there a way to install this module from shell, without starting Firefox and gettin MozRepl started?